Q. 56 from chapter 2 of a First Course to probability bySheldom Ross - Spinner's Problem
There are three spinners. Spinner 'a' contain numbers (1,5,9), spinner 'b' contains number (3,8,4) and spinner 'c' contains number (7,6,2).

Two players play the following game: Player A chosses one of the three spinners and the player B chooses one of the remaining two spinners. Both players then spin their spinner, and the one that lands on the higher number is declared the winner. Assuming that each spinner is equally likely to land in any of its 3 regions, would you rather be player A or player B? Explain you answer!
My Approach
Probability of getting any spinner: $\frac{1}{3}$
Probability of getting any number in spinner: $\frac{1}{3}$ 
Let $A_i$, $i\in1\le i\le9$ be event of getting the particular number.
Probability of winning $P(A_i)$:
$P(A_1) = 0$
$P(A_2) = \frac{1}{6}$
$P(A_3) = \frac{1}{3}$
$P(A_4) = \frac{1}{3}$
$P(A_5) = \frac{1}{2}$
$P(A_6) = \frac{2}{3}$
$P(A_7) = \frac{2}{3}$
$P(A_8) = \frac{5}{6}$
$P(A_9) = 1$
How can I approach further.
